# Docusign API: Tabs Wrongly Applied To Other Documents and Fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, docusignapi

I have been working with Docusign's API for some time now on a project for my company. The purpose is to allow for documents to be signed digitally which can put business processes into action. Recently, I have added a third document that, when a checkbox is checked, a third document is added to the envelope to be signed (this is where the `acc = True` comes in. However, the issue is that, specifically for this third document, anywhere on the other documents that the anchor string is, the fields get placed, resulting in tabs going not only to unintended fields, but unintended fields on unintended documents.

In all of my tabs, I have set the value `anchor_match_whole_word = 'true'`, and in the tabs for the third document, I have set the value `document_id = '3'`. Below is my code:

```
    signer1 = docusign.Signer(email = myClient.email, name = myClient.ainame, recipient_id = '1')
    signer2 = docusign.Signer(email = "myEmail@gmail.com", name = "Sam Sampleton", recipient_id = '2')

    sign_here1 = docusign.SignHere(document_id = '1', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = "Signature of individual authorized to act on behalf of customer", anchor_x_offset = ".2", anchor_y_offset = "1.25", anchor_units = "cms", tab_label = "Signature of individual authorized to act on behalf of customer",)

    sign_here2 = docusign.SignHere(document_id = '2', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'right', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = "Customer Signature", anchor_x_offset = ".5", anchor_y_offset = ".5", anchor_units = "cms", tab_label = "Customer Signature",)


    sign_here3 = docusign.SignHere(document_id = '2', recipient_id = '2', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'right', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = "Employee Signature", anchor_x_offset = ".5", anchor_y_offset = ".5", anchor_units = "cms", tab_label = "Employee Signature",)

    if acc == True:
        sign_here4 = docusign.SignHere(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Authorized Customer Signature', anchor_x_offset = '.05', anchor_y_offset = '-.5', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = "Authorized Customer Signature")

        sign_here5 = docusign.SignHere(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '2', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Authorized Mitech Partners Signature', anchor_x_offset = '1', anchor_y_offset = '-1', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = "Authorized Mitech Partners Signatures")

        cust_name = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Customer Name (Legal Name)', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Customer Name (Legal Name)')

        business_address = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Business Street Address:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Business Street Address')

        suite = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Suite#', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Suite#')

        city = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'City:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'City')

        state = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'State:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'State')

        zip_code = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Zip:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Zip Code')

        contact_name = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Customer Contact Name:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Customer Contact Name')

        contact_phone = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Customer Phone:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Customer Phone Number')

        extension = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Extension:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Extension')

        fax = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Fax:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Fax:')

        alternate_phone = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Alternate Phone:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Alternate Phone')

        email_address = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Email:', anchor_x_offset = '-.25', anchor_y_offset = '.35', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Customer Email')

        cust_print = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Printed Name', anchor_x_offset = '-.2', anchor_y_offset = '-.4', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Authorized Customer Printed Name')

        cust_title = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Title', anchor_x_offset = '-.2', anchor_y_offset = '-.4', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Authorized Customer Title')

        cust_date_signed = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '1', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Date Signed', anchor_x_offset = '-.1', anchor_y_offset = '-.4', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Customer Sign Date')

        ln_name = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '2', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Printed Name', anchor_x_offset = '-.2', anchor_y_offset = '-.4', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Employee Printed Name')

        ln_title = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '2', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Title', anchor_x_offset = '-.2', anchor_y_offset = '-.4', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'Employee Title')

        ln_date_signed = docusign.Text(document_id = '3', recipient_id = '2', anchor_horizontal_alignment = 'left', anchor_ignore_if_not_present = 'false', anchor_match_whole_word = 'true', anchor_string = 'Date Signed', anchor_x_offset = '-.1', anchor_y_offset = '-.4', anchor_units = 'cms', tab_label = 'My Company Date Signed')

    if acc == True:
        tabs1 = docusign.Tabs(sign_here_tabs = [sign_here1, sign_here2, sign_here4], text_tabs = [cust_name, business_address, suite, city, state, contact_name, contact_phone, extension, fax, alternate_phone, email_address, cust_print, cust_title], date_signed_tabs = [cust_date_signed])
        tabs2 = docusign.Tabs(sign_here_tabs = [sign_here3, sign_here5], text_tabs = [ln_name, ln_title], date_signed_tabs = [ln_date_signed])
    else:
        tabs1 = docusign.Tabs(sign_here_tabs = [sign_here1, sign_here2])
        tabs2 = docusign.Tabs(sign_here_tabs = [sign_here3])

    signers = []
    signer1.tabs = tabs1
    signer2.tabs = tabs2
    signers.append(signer1)
    signers.append(signer2)

    recipients = docusign.Recipients(signers = signers)

    envelope_definition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition(email_subject = "Please Sign the Following Documents", email_blurb = "Please sign the following documents to complete the process!" )

    with open(pdfpath1, 'rb') as signfile1, open(pdfpath2, 'rb') as signfile2, open(pdfpath3, 'rb') as signfile3:
        file_data1 = signfile1.read()
        doc = docusign.Document()
        base64_doc = base64.b64encode(file_data1).decode('utf-8')
        doc.document_base64 = base64_doc
        doc.name = "Info.pdf"

        doc.document_id = '1'
        file_data2 = signfile2.read()
        doc2 = docusign.Document()
        base64_doc2 = base64.b64encode(file_data2).decode('utf-8')
        doc2.document_base64 = base64_doc2
        doc2.name = "ServiceAgreement.pdf"
        doc2.document_id = '2'
        if acc == True:
            file_data3 = signfile3.read()
            doc3 = docusign.Document()
            base64_doc3 = base64.b64encode(file_data3).decode('utf-8')
            doc3.document_base64 = base64_doc3
            doc3.name = "ACC.pdf"
            doc3.document_id = '3'
            envelope_definition.documents = [doc, doc2, doc3]
        else:
            envelope_definition.documents = [doc, doc2]
    envelope_definition.recipients = recipients
    envelope_definition.status = 'sent'


    auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
    envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi()
    try:
        login_info = auth_api.login()
        login_accounts = login_info.login_accounts
        base_url, _ = login_accounts[0].base_url.split('/v2')
        api_client.host = base_url
        docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client

        envelope_summary = envelopes_api.create_envelope(login_accounts[0].account_id, envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
        print(envelope_summary)
        return 1
    except ApiException as e:
        raise Exception("Exception when calling DocuSign API: %s" % e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I expected to get all of my tabs placed in the appropriate places, in the appropriate documents, as I haven't had this issue before adding this third document. However, `Title` is appearing in every document where the word exists, as is `Printed Name`. `Printed Name` is appearing over both the customer's printed name field (labeled as "Printed Name"), as are the `Title` and `Date Signed` tabs. Furthermore, the `Customer Signature` field from `sign_here2` from the document with `document_id='2'` is appearing next to the `Authorized Customer Signature` tabs. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR -- ask your DocuSign technical contact or customer service to update your account's `Anchor Scope` setting to `document` and you'll be all set.

### Details

It's considered a "feature" that the anchor text search system looks in all documents in the envelope.

DocuSign has an account-level setting to change the `Anchor Scope` setting for the account from `whole envelope` to `document`. If the setting is `document`, then the `documentId` will be used to determine the document that will be searched for the anchor string.

The setting can only be changed by DocuSign. Contact customer support to have it changed.

An alternative pattern for using anchor text is to add additional text to the documents. Eg `/sn1/` to mark where the first signer's signature tab should go.

Since we don't want to see the ugly text string `/sn1/` in the document itself, the common work-around is to use the color white for the string `/sn1/` so it won't be seen on the page.

If you may have signers who use screen readers, you can spell it out since the screen reader will ignore the color of the text. Eg something like `/signer 1 signature area/` (But be sure to test, sometimes spaces are changed to other characters in the PDF and the text won't match.)

### Update

I have filed DocuSign internal enhancement request EC-1150 to make the scope settable via the API. If you'd benefit from this enhancement, ask your DocuSign technical or business contact to add your organization's information to the ticket.

Comment: I see. Would the workaround for multiple signatures on the same document just be to place them manually?

Comment: Or rather, to use coordinates?

Comment: Use coordinates, reference a template where they're manually placed, or use unique strings for each tag and color the text white so it can't be seen